# Can't find where the problem is: Run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have recently created an Excel file where I have a few macros.
With the help of one of the forum members here, I managed to use the following:

```
Sub Name_Range()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  With Worksheets("DB_Elements")
    For i = 1 To 85
      j = (i - 1) * 14 + 3
      ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=.Range("B" & j), RefersTo:=.Range("B" & j & ":X" & (j + 11))
    Next
  
  End With

End Sub
```

However, when I want to run the macro, it gives me the run-time error '1004'. Upon debugging, I see the problem is in the line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=.Range("B" & j), RefersTo:=.Range("B" & j & ":X" & (j + 11))
```

Not sure what is happening. Two months ago, the macro used to run perfectly well. Nothing has been changed. Any ideas?

Comment: `.Range("B" & j & ":X" & (j + 11)).Address`?

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, another workbook open that contains a sheet `"DB_Elements"`? Try `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB_Elements")`

Comment: What GSerg said. Also, does `.Range("B" & j)` hold a value & is it valid for a name (i.e. no funky characters)?

Comment: `Address` is not needed - works with a Range variable. If name is not valid, you get a 1004, but the error text is different

Comment: Most likely and invalid Name. When you see the error dialog, select `Debug` then, in the Immediate window, type `?.range("b" & j)` and report the results.

Comment: @FunThomas No, no other workbooks open containing a sheet "DB_Elements". Tried it also with what you propose, doesn't work, still asks for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

### Naming Multiple Ranges

- This may not solve your problems but may shed a light on what's happening.
- After running it, study the information in the `Immediate` window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Name_Range()

    With Worksheets("DB_Elements")
        
        Dim rg As Range
        Dim NN As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim wasNotAdded As Boolean

        For i = 1 To 85
            
            j = (i - 1) * 14 + 3
            Set rg = .Range("B" & j)
            NN = CStr(rg.Value)
            
            On Error GoTo NameError
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=NN, RefersTo:=rg.Resize(12, 23)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If wasNotAdded Then
                Debug.Print "Cannot use '" & NN & "' from cell '" _
                    & rg.Address(0, 0) & "'."
                wasNotAdded = False
            'Else
                'Debug.Print "Added the name '" & NN & "' for the range '" _
                    & rg.Resize(12, 23).Address(0, 0) & "'."
            End If
        
        Next
    
    End With
    
    Exit Sub

NameError:
    wasNotAdded = True
    Resume Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

@VBasic2008

It did in some way solve the problem, meaning that when I run the macro now, it doesn't give me the run-time error '1004'.
Here is what is written in the `Immediate` window:

Cannot use '' from cell 'B59'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B73'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B87'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B101'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B115'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B129'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B143'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B157'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B171'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B185'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B199'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B213'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B227'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B241'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B255'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B269'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B283'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B297'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B311'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B325'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B339'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B353'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B367'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B381'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B395'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B409'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B423'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B437'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B451'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B465'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B479'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B493'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B507'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B521'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B535'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B549'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B563'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B577'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B591'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B605'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B619'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B633'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B647'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B661'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B675'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B689'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B703'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B717'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B731'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B745'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B759'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B773'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B787'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B801'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B815'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B829'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B843'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B857'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B871'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B885'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B899'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B913'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B927'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B941'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B955'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B969'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B983'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B997'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1011'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1025'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1039'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1053'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1067'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1081'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1095'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1109'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1123'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1137'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1151'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1165'.
Cannot use '' from cell 'B1179'.

Comment: These cell addresses indicate where it was looking for a name that couldn't be created. If you uncomment the `Else` and the `following Debug` lines, you will also get the information on which names were created. You could out-comment the previous `Debug` line to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me!